# Adding view to Toolbar removed title and subtitle

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Previously, I had a toolbar that had a Title and a Subtitle. What I want to do now is add a custom view to the right of the subtitle. However, when I add a view to the Toolbar, it removes the Title and the Subtitle. Is this intended behaviour?

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/count_label"
               android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting layout to right of subtitle you can put your title , subtitle in a layout and other widgets that you want and inflate over toolbar.

Comment: But there is a built in Title and Subtitle, are you saying that I need to recreate it?

Comment: Like actionbar also built in title and subtitle and we can putcustom layout to actionabr. Similarly, toolbar has to be done.

Comment: Refer here for toolbar - http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html